# version mismatch of maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: maven

I have this lines under our pom.xml file

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <jdkLevel>1.6</jdkLevel>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I am using apache-maven-2.2.1  version . 
Will it be any problem as the versions of maven-compiler-plugin and maven Version does not match ??

Please suggest , thank you very much .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The versions of maven and its plugins ***never*** match. There is no coordination of the releases. It is very rare for there to be compatibility issues and when they exist they are documented on the plugin documentation pages.